# Azure command line tool, can't import `cygrpc`

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working through the Azure function tutorial on [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) and I followed it word for word, however, when I go to run a local server `func host start` in my error logs I am seeing `ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc'`?

All of the errors seem to be coming from the azure-functions-core-tools `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools`

Here are the [full logs](https://pastebin.com/K4RSiqTA) with the traceback

Comment: I use pyenv to manage different versions of python and I installed 32-bit version of 3.6 vs 64-bit and this error is an issue on the github repo for 32-bit.  I installed the 64-bit version and everything worked. If you get this error, make sure you double check which bit version you have installed.

Comment: Is that mean you solve your problem by installing right version? If so, you could write it as an reply to let other know.

Comment: @spitfiredd add your comment as an answer for yourself, which helps future people

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue even when the versions were matching, but running `func init` before `func start` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

This error will come up if you are using 32-bit python, there is currently an open issue on their [Github page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1462).

If you are using `pyenv` to manage your installations you first want to verify that you are using the `64 bit` version on python.  To do that pop open a terminal and run `python` and if you are running the `64 bit` version you should see:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

If you see that you are running `32 bit` python then you will want to install the right version. If you run

```
pyenv install -l
```

you will get a list of all available versions of python.  The `64 bit` versions usually share the similar prefix `amd64` so look for the version you want with that prefix and install that.  As of 9/10/2019 Azure functions only support 3.6.x, I installed `3.6.5-amd64`, there is also `3.6.8-amd64`

```
pyenv install 3.6.5-amd64
```

You can then verify installed versions with:

```
pyenv versions
```

Comment: I'm running 64bit py 3.7.4 and still getting the error